# reading individual line in a file with python

Tags: python

How is this wrong? It seems like I am doing this right but every time. I have tried changing the `readline` part to `read` but that didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
f = open("pg1062.txt","r").read()
print f.readline(1)
print f.readline(2)
print f.readline(3)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
 print f.readline(1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

Comment: Can you show the exact code where you are trying to use readline?

Comment: Guess what you think the type of `f` is, then run the first line in a REPL to find out if you're right.

Comment: I see, your problem is at first line. `f = open("pg1062.txt","r").read()`. Just remove last `.read()` and it will be fixed. see final code down in post.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at this line

```
f = open("pg1062.txt","r").read()
```

just remove `.read()` and your problem will be fixed. Your final code should look like.

```
f = open("pg1062.txt","r")
print f.readline()
print f.readline()
print f.readline()
```

And if you want to print all lines from text file, see code below

```
f = open("pg1062.txt","r")
for line in f:
    print line
```

Comment: it doesn't really print the whole line. it basically prints the first letters of the line

Comment: yes, because f.readline(1) prints only first character (as you are using in your code). if you want to print whole line, you need to remove parameter from readline. see updated example

Comment: again, if you print all lines from file, it will look different from what is mentioned above. It doesn't clear form your question what are you intending

Answer (score 1):

This uses a loop to print your lines.

```
f = open("pg1062.txt", 'r')
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if line == "":
        break
    print(line)
```

If you want to only print a specific number of lines, then do something like this:

```
f = open("pg1062.txt", 'r')
count = 1
while count < 4:
    line = f.readline()
    if line == "":
        break
    print(line)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a duplicate. At any rate, anything above Python 2.4 should use a `with` block.

```
with open("pg1062.txt", "r") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print(line)
```

If you happen to want them in a list:

```
with open("pg1062.txt", "r") as fin:
    lines = [line for line in fin] # keeps newlines at the end
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in fin] # deletes the newlines
```

or more or less equivalently

```
with open("pg1062.txt", "r") as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines() # keeps newlines at the end
    lines = fin.read().splitlines() # deletes the newlines
```